# Advice: What is Worldbuilding?

Tags: discussion, advice

The official statement about worldbuilding in the Help Center is this:

> Worldbuilding Stack Exchange is a site for designers, writers, artists, gamers and enthusiasts to get help creating imaginary worlds.
>
> World building includes geography, culture and creatures for the world, not to mention magic and planetary physics, in short, everything from the physics underlying your reality to the entire universe you want to build.

That definition has proven to be very vague and doesn't track well with how users are using the Stack today. The purpose of this post is to provide a list of acceptable definitions of what worldbuilding is specifically in regard to this Stack.

*This Stack was never designed to embrace or meant to embrace all forms of worldbuilding. Some simply don't fit Stack Exchange's fairly rigid question-and-answer format.*

**The Rules...**

1. Be concise. If you need a page or more of explanation to describe your proposed definition of worldbuilding, it's wrong by definition. A good definition is no more than one paragraph long (4-6 sentences).
2. Be well focused. If you have multiple definitions for the community to consider, please post them as separate answers.
3. If you believe a proposed definition *isn't quite right,* it is permissible to modify that answer and duplicate it as an alternative. HOWEVER... I recognize that this might be an abused privilege, so I'm begging the community not to quibble over small things. It would be good form to ask about your concern in a comment to see if it was something the respondent overlooked before jumping to posting a modified version.
4. Please keep Stack Exchange's model and rules in mind. It's tempting to use this Meta question to advance a definition of worldbuilding that doesn't fit inside our Stack Exchange Overlords' expectations, but it really is their site and they have the privilege of setting those rules.
5. Please up-vote and/or down-vote as many answers as you wish.
6. Sort the answers by highest score. What's on top is what we like to see the most. Every step down from there increases the likelihood of a question being closed for not being about worldbuilding according to the Help Center.

Comment: The two answers below make no mention of "culture and creatures". Can we expect this to follow?

Comment: I'm honestly not really sure what you want to do here. Is it about defining different subtypes of worldbuilding like in your answers? Or is it about rewriting a better, single definition of worldbuilding, since your "question" raises that the tour+help-center is vague?

Comment: @Tortliena You're concern is, honestly, on-point. I think that in the good old days (before Monica was fired) there was a clear idea of what "worldbuilding" mean on this Stack. I further believe that our narrow focus is no longer narrow. Therefore, as inconvenient as it may be, I must remain open to both ideas: what *specific* types of worldbuilding are we interested in and what *general* definition would best suit the site? Yes, those ultimately should be separate questions - and I can see this evolving into two finalizing specific questions... but for now, we need to gather some data.

Comment: @MichaelK I tossed one common type and one uncommon type out there to get the ball rolling. I might add one or two that deal with creatures and culture - notably culture as this Stack has had the hardest time dealing with cultural worldbuilding due to its frequent dependency on story elements or choices.

Comment: @JBH _" I tossed one common type and one uncommon type out there to get the ball rolling."_ Gotcha! That is good. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Realistic Worldbuilding**

Realistic worldbuilidng is the act of creating an imaginary world that reflects, to the community's best ability, known science. It is limited to the hard sciences including but not limited to chemistry, biology, climate, astronomy and celestial mechanics. It excludes cultural and behavioral worldbuilding that have no scientific basis beyond statistical analysis (making them too opinion-based for this type of worldbuilding). The goal of realistic worldbuilding is to hybridize the imaginary world with the real universe. The more fantastic the imaginary idea the worldbuilder is trying to hybridize into the real universe, the more likely the question will be rejected as realistic worldbuilding.

Answer (score 0):

**Chaotic Worldbuilding**

Chaotic worldbuilding imagines a world or universe with few or no established physical laws. The process of worldbuilding, however, is not lawless or without structure. Worldbuilding requires an underlying consistency to be valid on this Stack. This does not preclude the assumption that characters experiencing the imagined world or universe are incapable of perceiving that consistency. Worldbuilding of this nature focuses on expressing the consequences of chaos, entropy, lawlessness, and unpredictability.

Answer (score 0):

Worldbuilding is the act of establishing facts about some fictional world. All facts are established at the worldbuilder's discretion. They can choose to impose rules on their worldbuilding process as they see fit. We are not here to judge someone's worldbuilding process or challenge facts about their world that they've already established.

If someone wants help determining the weight of a 50 story spider, it's our job to help them come up with a weight, not explain to them all the ways that a 50 story spider is physically impossible in the real world. Similarly if someone asks "Is X possible?" we should remind them that they get to choose what is and isn't possible in their world, and it's up to them to articulate the restrictions they've chosen to impose on what they choose to permit in their world.

With respect to this site any question that can be shown to be establishing some fact about a fictional world can be considered on topic for this site. It should be emphasized that, **just because a question is about establishing some fact of your world does not automatically make it appropriate for this site**. A question also needs to be asked in a way that follows the SE model. All questions need to be:

- About a real worldbuilding problem you're facing
- Clearly asked
- Based in facts and experience, not opinions

  - Importantly this means no idea generation, brainstorming, or story based questions
- Specific

  - A question should not have many valid answers
  - It should be possible to answer a question concisely without needing to write a whole book of prose.

Answer (score 0):

Worldbuilding is first and foremost Art: the creation of an alternate world, a secondary creation or faerie in which places and events and people that may or may not exist *here* take form and exist *there*, interacting in new and different ways.

When God was about to create the world by his Word, the letters of the alphabet descended from the terrible and august crown whereon they were engraved with a pen of flaming fire. They stood round about, and one after the other spake and entreated: "Create the world through me!"

When we subcreate such a place as an alternate world, we are in fact reaching out into the Dreaming, into the very Source of our own existence; we are reaching within, into the creative urge; we touch another reality and give it shape and form in this reality.